# Sha256 checksum difference between Java vs Linux

Tags: java, linux, shell, checksum, sha256

Am writing a application which calculate the checksum of file before sending it to downstream. At downstream application, linux shell script are used to process the files. It is noticed that checksum calculated from Java application doesn't matches that calculated using Linux command 'sha256sum'.

Below is code snippet in JAVA:

```
public static String calculateChecksum(File file) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream inputStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(file)) {
        return DigestUtils.sha256Hex(inputStream); //from org.apache.commons.codec.digest
    }
}
```

Using java api i get checksum value as :

```
d05a9724479af8a7a20f7acff3629b0dd8aaa447ec821b4b31708bc43eb99841
```

but when the checksum is calculated for for same file using Linux command '`sha256sum <file>`' then it gives

```
37f865eb2a3956e3f903eaaf92f0459143cf9b9699a7d1d6bc91bfc89ad5eb8c
```

Below is what the file contain. You can create file with below content. Am using abc.txt. It has newlines.

```
dscscsdvcs

kkl
```

Can some suggest what's going wrong here? File is not corrupted. Contents are identical at source and destination.

Comment: Do you get the same checksum for e.g. an empty file?

Comment: @choroba …yes for empty file checksum matches.

Comment: I was able to compile your code, it returns the same checksum for a file of 953 MB as the sha256sum utility.

Comment: @choroba, i have added the content of file. Please copy the text into abc.txt and then try calculating the checksum value.  Have updated the earlier checksum values.

Comment: What's reason for -1 for this question?

Comment: what is your file size, Can you hexdump it ?

Comment: Does the file have the same line terminators at both peers? or have they been mangled? Files the same size at both ends? Same content?

Comment: Size is 15 bytes. File at both end is exactly same. In fact  its a same file copied as it is to linux system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get both the digests from two different files. See their hexdumps:

d05a9724479af8a7a20f7acff3629b0dd8aaa447ec821b4b31708bc43eb99841:

```
00000000: 6473 6373 6373 6476 6373 0d0a 0d0a 6b6b  dscscsdvcs....kk
00000010: 6c                                       l
```

37f865eb2a3956e3f903eaaf92f0459143cf9b9699a7d1d6bc91bfc89ad5eb8c:

```
00000000: 6473 6373 6373 6476 6373 0a0a 6b6b 6c    dscscsdvcs..kkl
```

The difference is end of line type, *nix versus MSWin.

The size of the files is not the same, it's 15 versus 17 bytes.

Java gives the same results.

Comment: Thanks choroba for checking. How can we handle this in Java?

Comment: What do you want to handle? I'm getting different digests both in the shell and in Java.

Comment: How do you copy the file from one system to another?

Comment: If you want to transfer the file as is, use the `binary` transfer type.